# How to preserve the ending values of an animation?

Tags: android, animation, position, adt

I use `API 10`.
I have an `ImageView` nested inside of a `LinearLayout`. The `ImageView` has an `OnClickListener` (or an `OnTouchListener`, I'm sure which one I ll use at the end). The ImageView is centered on the screen, and when clicked it performs the following animation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    >
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:toAlpha="0" 
        android:duration ="500"
        />

    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p"
        android:duration ="1000"
    />
</set>
```

The problem is that after the animation ends, it returns to its first position, faded out to 0, but it is still clickable even if it doesn't show up. I click on an empty space where the ImageView was first positioned, and it performs the the animation again. Like clicking a ghost.
How do I make it so that the ImageView stays at the position written at `android:toXDelta` ??

Comment: You're misinterpreting the phenomenon you see. The tween animation you use really only moves a bitmap, not the `View` itself. In other words, it creates the illusion of moving the `View`. If you have to use tween animations due to compatibility, the solution would be to listen for the end of the animation and then change attributes of the layout, e.g. gravity or such, to actually place the View where it appears to be. Or in your case, set the View's visibility to `GONE` or `enabled` to `false`.

Comment: Thanks, the setVisibility() one works. The enable one I don't how to do it. But the problem is that visibility doesn't work for the LinearLayout, cause I plan on adding more Views inside it, and I don't want to setVisibility for each item, but for the parent. Can you post the code for visibility on LinearLayout and the code for enabled?

Comment: Can you please re-phrase the remaining problem you now have, because I don't quite understand how the `LinearLayout` contributes.

Comment: Can you tell me what is inside the LinearLayout, and what effect you want to have? Should it vanish altogether? What exactly does not work, what is still visible, or what receives clicks, or what other problematic behaviour does it show?

Comment: I animated now the parent the ImageView is nested in, and that's the LinearLayout. While the setVisibility() works for the ImageView, when I try it on the LinearLayout it doesn't work.

Comment: Inside the LinearLayout are 5 ImageView which can be clicked. I don't them after the animation ends to be clicked. Can I setEnabled to the whole LinearLayout? Or do I have to do it for each ImageView?

Comment: You can either set the visibility of the ImageView directly or traverse your LinearLayout subtree and call `setVisibility()` for all children. You'd use `getChildCount()` and `getChildAt()` for that and should you have another `ViewGroup` inside your LienarLayout, you'd check that via `instanceof` and treat those children recursively, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an animationListener to your animation to tackle the problem, I created this simple fonction:

```
public void startAnimation(final View v, final int animationResourceId, AnimationListener l){
    Animation anim;

    if(v!=null){    // can be null, after change of orientation
        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(),resId);
        v.setAnimation(anim);
        anim.setAnimationListener(l);
        v.startAnimation(anim);                 
    }
}
```

Then every time I need to animate an view, I can do something like this:

```
startAnimation(myView, R.anim.my_anim, new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                myView.setVisibility(View.GONE);    
            }
        });
```